# Prove that no bipartite graph of order $3$ or more is Hamiltonian connected

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that no bipartite graph of order $3$ or more is Hamiltonian connected

> A graph $G$ is **Hamiltonian connected** if for every pair $u,v$ of vertices of $G$, there is a Hamiltonian $u-v$ path in $G$
>
> Theorem 3.23: Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ such that $deg(v) \geq \frac{n+1}{2}$ then $G$ is Hamiltonian connected.

this is what I got so far

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with 2 partites $U$ and $V$. Assume that $G$ is connected, otherwise, we have nothing to prove. We will prove this by induction

Base: $n=3$, then either $|U|=1$  and $|V|=2$ or the other way around, there is a vertex of degree $1$, which is less than $\frac{n+1}{2}$, so $K_{1,2}$  isn’t Hamiltonian connected.

Inductive: Assume that for $n=k$, G isn’t Hamiltonian connected. That mean there is at least one vertex $v$ of degree less than $\frac{k+1}{2}$. Add a new vertex $w$ the connect $w$ to every vertex on the opposite partite

Case 1: $w$ is on the same partite of $v$ then $deg(v)$ is unchange, and $G$ still isn't Hamitonian connected.

Case 2: $w$ is on the opposite partite of $v$, Can this change my result?

Comment: Having a vertex of degree less than $(n + 1)/2$ does not imply non-Hamiltonian connectedness.  See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that no complete bipartite graph is Hamiltonian connected, as any bipartite graph can be obtained from a complete one by removing edges.  And removing edges cannot make a graph Hamiltonian connected.

So let $G$ be a complete bipartite graph with parts $X$ and $Y$.
If $|X| = |Y|$, take $u, v \in X$ (why must $u,v$ exist, by the way ?).  No Hamiltonian path can start at $u$ and finish at $v$, since any Hamiltonian path starting in $X$ must finish in $Y$.

If $|X| < |Y|$, take $u \in Y, v \in X$.  No Hamiltonian path can start at $u$ and finish at $v$, since any Hamiltonian path starting in $Y$ must finish in $Y$.

Similar when $|X| > |Y|$.

In fact I didn't even need to suppose $G$ was a complete bipartite graph...

Answer (score 0):

I think the complete bipartite graph is Hamiltonian connected.

Comment: complete bipartite with odd order isn't Hamiltonian connected, because if you start at a vertex in smaller partite, you will left out one vertex, but the bipartite with even order is Hamiltonian connected, at least that is what I see from the graph.